# does the django-firebird 1.5.0.rc.2 driver work with Python 3.3?

Tags: python, django, firebird

I am trying to use Firebird with django but when I install it with .

```
pip install django-firebird
```

I get the following error

```
    File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\firebird\base.py", line 9
  except ImportError, e:
                    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\firebird\creation.py", line 76
  print "_rollback_works"
                        ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Example code in the base.py is as follows :-

```
        except Database.IntegrityError, e:
        raise utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*self.error_info(e, query, param_list[0])), sys.exc_info()[2]
```

I am running Windows, Python 3.3 and Django 1.5.

Is this a syntax change with Python 3?

The package says it works with python 2.6+

Regards

Any ideas?

Comment: When something says it works with python 2.6+ it means it doesn't work with python 3.x.

Comment: I kind of figured thats what the problem might be.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2:

```
 except ImportError, e:

 print "_rollback_works"
```

In Python 3:

```
 //Exception handling syntax changes slightly, "as"
 except ImportError as err:

 //print is now a function print()
 print ("_rollback_works")
```

That's why you get that errors.

Comment: Maybe you should pull this issue to their project

Comment: I will. It looks like I will have to stick with Python 2 for now or wait until they update it for Python 3. Thanks.

Comment: Just got a response from the developer. He is about to commit a version that will work with Python 3. Happy days!

Comment: Looks like he committed it: https://twitter.com/maxirobaina/status/320286745738477568